# Removing Electron bootstrapping from an Angular app

Tags: angular, electron, cross-platform

I inherited source code with no documentation. It's meant to be a web application to run in a browser. When I review the code, it appears to be bootstrapped with Electron. There is a `main.js` and the package.json has this line:

`"main": "main.js"`

I built the application and attempted to run it using `ng build && electron .` and it opens a desktop app with just the menu (no UI).

I am new to Electron and understand it's a way to build desktop apps using web technologies, but did the team that developed this project intend this app to be cross platform (run on web & windows). If so, how can this be deployed to be a browsed based application? Or should I be thinking along the lines of removing the electron code and make it a plain vanilla Angular app?

Comment: Haming main entrypoint to `main.js` doesn't mean anything if it's truly electron bootstrap or not. With given info, it's not possible to verify if project includes some specific related with electron.

Comment: It doesn't have any electron specific references in the project. Is there an easy way to remove the electron ref and run it in a browser as a regular angular app?

Comment: maybe I misunderstood q totally, if your project don't have any ref to electron what's left to be removed? If you think project is somehow related with electron, would like to know more about details why - as said above, there's nothing I can tell if project is really electron related or not.